# Step down 20V DC to 9V DC

Tags: power-supply, dc

What would be the best way to convert 20V DC to 9V DC? Can I use a simple potential divider network and regulate the output? If not, then what's the harm in it? I intend to use the output to power my AVR development board. I've seen people using complex DC-DC converters. What are the advantages of such devices over normal potential divider network? Please help.

Comment: Below answer is correct, and if you don't want to build a switching regulator from scratch search for LM2596 on e-bay and you'll see you can buy pre-made boards for a dollar or two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A voltage divider made up of resistors isn't the best way to drop your voltage because if the current drawn by the load changes, the voltage across it will also change. (Do [a basic search](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=voltage%20divider) on resistor voltage dividers for more.)

There are two primary ways to regulate or drop voltage: linear and switching.

An [LM317](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/LM/LM317.pdf) for example, is an adjustable linear regulator which can easily regulate 20V down to 9V provided you aren't exceeding its current rating of 1.5A.

From the datasheet, here is a schematic of typical usage:

[image: LM317 Typical Application]

However, linear regulators such as this produce heat, and are not the most efficient way to step voltage down.

Switching regulators (or a *buck* converter) essentially switch on and off at a high frequency and provide regulated voltage with greater efficiency. There are all-in-one packages such as ST's [MC34063ECN](http://www.st.com/st-web-ui/static/active/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/CD00001232.pdf). I picked this example because it has similar current handling as the LM317, is inexpensive, and is also a through-hole component in case that's what you're looking for.

Again, from the datasheet, here's a schematic of typical step-down usage:

[image: MC34063ECN Step-Down Usage]

As you can see, it is a little more complicated, but worthwhile if you need greater efficiency.

Finally, don't forget that switching power supplies might be an option. Unless you *need* to derive 9V from a DC source, you might simply consider a 9V regulated switching power supply that gets power from the mains.

---

**Edit:**

I should also mention that an [LM7809](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/LM/LM7805.pdf) is a fixed 9V linear regulator which would require fewer external components. However its current limit is 1A. An AVR development board likely won't require that amount of current unless you're also powering some external components.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how much current you need and if you will ever use batteries. There are 3-pin DC/DC from muRata and TI that are great but I have not seen 9V.

These are all over eBay http://www.ebay.com/itm/New-DC-DC-LM2596-Step-Down-Adjustable-Power-Supply-Module-Converter-DC-1-3V-35V-/380755874794?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item58a6d193ea and an amazing price with shipping included. I might get some myself.

A linear regulator will be very inefficient and likely run hot with 11 volts across it. The DC/DC or switch mode power supply is much better in most cases. The eBay and other hobby designs simply follow the manufacturer's recommended sample circuit and as a result are close to optimal.

A divider is OK if you just need a reference voltage and are taking a tiny current compared to current through the divider. Definitely not OK as a power source*. The value of the load resistance (proportional to the current used by the AVR board) will be changing all the time which would make the voltage at the divider node change. To work, you would need small resistance in the divider and large current which would mean high power resistors. Find the current required by your AVR. Calculate a resistance to allow that current with  11 volts across it (the 20 volts minus the 9 for the AVR) and calculate power, I*I*R. Or simpler, use power=VI and that will be 11V*ARVcurrent. Say for example 200mA, then you get P=2.2W. If you run servos or LED strips or anything fun, you will need more current. Count on needing a 5 or 10 watt resistor and now it is getting a bit ridiculous. Aside from the heat, you would have to adjust it all the time. By the time you make it work you will have built a regulator.

*I should say that with caution. 100 years ago dividers and shunts the size of a trash can with long coils of heavy gauge tungsten or nichrome were used with a big rotary switch to control street car motors. Air had to flow through. They were like a giant toaster inside and used for braking too I think.